# Why is it impossible to import some python submodules?

Tags: python

For example, I cannot import the submodule `numpy.core.setup`, the same goes for the submodule `numpy.distutils.msvc9compiler` and many others.

**EDIT:**

Okay, here's a fragment of the code.

```
from importlib import import_module
from pkgutil import walk_packages
import sys
import operator


def get_attr(module, attr):
    return operator.attrgetter(attr.split('.', 1)[1])(module)


def isimported(module_name):
    return module_name in sys.modules


def get_submodules(module_name):
    submodules = {}
    module = import_module(module_name)
    for loader, name, is_pkg in walk_packages(module.__path__, module.__name__ + '.'):
        if isimported(name):
            submodules[name] = get_attr(module, name)
        else:
            try:
                submodules[name] = __import__(name)
            except ImportError:
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_submodules('numpy')
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: And show us the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: @ifconfig well I used `pkgutil.walk_packages` to list all the submodules of the `numpy` module. Then I found out that some modules have not been imported. A couple of them are mentioned above. So basically if you try to import them like so: `import numpy.core.setup` you will get an import error. So it doesn't have much to do with the code I'm writing.

Comment: Please edit your relevant code into your question. In most cases, the solution *definitely* depends on the context.

Comment: @ifconfig okay, I've edited the troublesome piece of code into the question.

Comment: The thing is that `walk_packages` doesn't import all the submodules, so they should be forced. But as user2357112 said, some of the objects returned by `walk_packages` are not submodules. So it would make sense to filter them out somehow. But is it really possible?

Comment: @JohnGordon Well the exact error message is somewhat big. And it's something awkward. Most of it is some usage info and the first two lines are: 
`Could not locate executable icc`,  `Could not locate executable ecc`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy/core/setup.py` isn't designed to be a submodule. It's part of the NumPy build system. It relies on things that only exist while NumPy is building, and if you try to import it in an actual installed NumPy, it fails because the things it was relying on aren't there.

Comment: Okay, and seems like it's not the only one. And taking into account the code I've edited into th question, how do I avoid importing it? I tried catching the ImportError exception but there are still some problems. Actually, I'd like to filter out things like that. Don't know if it's possible though.

Comment: @Foobard: Awkward special-casing, probably. Maybe you could add a way to tell your `get_submodules` function to skip some files and folders. `numpy.distutils` and any `setup.py` files should probably be skipped.

Comment: No, that's not a solution. First of all because I need it to work with different modules. Filtering out ".setup" files won't help much cos there are other modules like that.